# Non-Free Module for P7zip (p7zip-rar)

Tags: extract, 7zip, rar

I've installed P7zip from the Ubuntu Software Center. Under "Optional add-ons" I see a non-free rar module. Is this add-on a trial only? If so, how can I buy the full version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Free as in speech, not free as in beer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre). The principle license of the rar module is the unRAR license. From the [copyright](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/multiverse/p/p7zip-rar/p7zip-rar_9.20.1~ds.1-3/copyright):

> Files in folders
>
> ```
> CPP/7zip/Compress/Rar/
> ```
>
> are licensed under "unRAR license + GNU LGPL" license.
>
> "unRAR license + GNU LGPL" means that you must follow  GNU LGPL in all
>   aspects while it is in agreement  with unRAR license. But you can not
>   break unRAR license rules. It means that unRAR license is main license
>   in that pair.

The unRAR license is [not a free licence](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:Unrar?rd=Licensing/Unrar), hence the module is non-free. It is freeware, and you don't have to pay anything for using it to its fullest capabilities.